# Updated row is not working in gridview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been created student details page.

Here is my code for update:

```
protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            if (Textid.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_updatestudentdetail", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Textid.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Textemail.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobilenum", Textmobilenum.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EC_id", Textcurricular.SelectedValue);

                try
                {
                    string filename = Image1.ImageUrl.Substring(Image1.ImageUrl.IndexOf('/')+1);
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images"));
                    foreach (string f in files) File.Delete(f);
                    if (fileupload.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
                    {      
                        filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower();
                        string uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtension;
                        fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + uniqueFileName));

                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", (filename.Length > 0) ? "Images/" + uniqueFileName : string.Empty);
                    }                    
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    btnsub.Text = ex.Message;
                }

                    Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");
            }
```

The insertion works fine., when i edit the row from gridview and doing some changes and update, the updated row is not working.

After insertion the row in grid view like this: [screenshot-1](http://s17.postimg.org/kfim4buvj/image.jpg)

after edit and update the row same in gridview like this: [screenshot-2](http://s17.postimg.org/k7zklk9an/image.jpg)

so what is my mistake in my update code?

Can anyone guide me to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: can anyone help me....

Comment: Did you check if any exception occurred during `ExecuteNonQuery()`? Put a breakpoint inside the catch block and debug. As you are _redirecting_ to another page (exception or not), the exception message you are setting in `btnsub.Text` will never be shown. Better put that `Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx")` _inside_ the `try` block.